# not show map on android emulator in new version 11.0 android studio

Tags: android

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wD9nR.png)I updated the android studio and I created a new project from the map activity but the android studio emulator shows the output: won't run without google play services which are not supported by your device in android

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

you need to create a new emulator that has google play services, when you go to create device, while choosing a device you'll notice that some device have the google play store logo next to it, you'll need to choose one of these